# Programming java to determine a symmetrical word

Tags: java, math, integer, symmetry

I am new here,  but I am having hard time figuring out how to write a code to determine an input of word and see if the first is matching with the end of the word. You may input abba and get answer it's evenly symmetric and aba is oddly symmetric.

Please show me how:(

Just two main things.

**first** 
I want to know if it's oddly or evenly amount of letter(number of letter divided by 2,if it's ending with 0.5, it's oddly symmetric,
if is an integer it's evenly symmetric.

**second**
I want to get (i.e 1=n,2=n-1,3=n-2...) position of the letter in the word to be the main idea of the execution.If there is a last letter in the oddly symmetric word, ignore the last remaining letter.

I appreciate any headstart or idea:) Thanks!

Thanks KDiTraglia, I made the code and compiled and here is what I put. I am not getting any further.

Reported problem:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    reverse cannot be resolved or is not a field
    reverse cannot be resolved or is not a field
    Syntax error, insert ") Statement" to complete IfStatement

This is what i got from, KDiTraglia's help

```
public class WordSymmetric {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 String word = "abccdccba";


if ( (word.length() % 2) == 1 ) {
    System.out.println("They are oddly symmetric");
    //odd
}
else {
    System.out.println("They are evenly symmetric");
    //even
}

int halfLength = word.length() / 2;
String firstHalf = word.substring(0, halfLength);
String secondHalf = word.substring(halfLength, word.length());

System.out.println(secondHalf.reverse());

if (firstHalf.equals(secondHalf.reverse()) {
    System.out.println("They match");
    //they match
}
```

}
}

Comment: You may want to show some code where you try to do this.  A simple approach is to reverse the input string and then some comparison is needed.

Comment: pretty sure you are just missing a right parenthesis after the if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator to determine whether the word has an even or odd number of letters (% in java)

```
if ( (word.length % 2) == 1 ) {
    //odd
}
else {
    //even
}
```

then just split the string in half and compare the reverse of the end with the front

```
int halfLength = word.length / 2;
String firstHalf = word.substring(0, halfLength);
String secondHalf = word.substring(halfLength, word.length);
if (firstHalf.equals(secondHalf.reverse()) {
    //they match
}
```

something like this should work, I just wrote it up real quick, might need to make a few changes to match java syntax.

Comment: @hidralisk Basic enough to be a SO question I think, don't know why all the downvotes, this is probably how I would have liked to learn it at this time.  Seeing a very basic programming example helps a lot I think, and it's his first question ever, if trends continue obviously can't continue to give the full answer for more advanced questions, but this question is so basic it's like a building block you have to learn somewhere...

Comment: The problem here is [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). The question was like "I can't resolve the problem by myself, please do the dirty job for me". Remember one of the main rules: [Stack Overflow won't do your homework for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128572/182862).